# mono log4net FileAppender won't write my message

Tags: c#, mono, log4j, log4net-appender

I'm ported one of our mvc 4 project to mono. Everything works fine but log4net not write my messages to file.

For instance;

```
_logger.InfoFormat("Address {0} Callback to {1}", receiveAddress.input_address, receiveAddress.callback_url);

[2013-10-11 05:25:39,750 [Threadpool worker] ERROR WrapperAPI.Controllers.NotificationController
```

My conversion pattern is;

```
<conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
```

log4net not write message section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I remove '[%property{NDC}]' from conversion pattern it's running. I think '[%property{NDC}]' and mono have problems.